# Can / should I suppress these warnings on release build when using the UIAutomationClient with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-ui-automation

I am building an application using the UIAutomationClient with C#. I am not using the managed version of the library, but the COM version:

[image]

The application is working perfectly as expected in both Debug and Release mode, but I am seeing a lot of warnings when compiling it in Release mode. I am getting two different types of warnings, changing the types and method names of course:

- Processing COM reference "UIAutomationClient" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll". At least one of the arguments for 'IUIAutomation2.SafeArrayToRectNativeArray' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate.
- Processing COM reference "UIA" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll". The type library importer could not convert the signature for the member 'UIAutomationMethodInfo.pParameterNames'.

Is there any way to fix the project so these warnings are not displayed? If not, is it safe to simply suppress these warnings?

Comment: Try adding this `<ResolveComReferenceSilent>True</ResolveComReferenceSilent>` in your project file. Right after `<PropertyGroup>`. Or rebuild the `.tlb`, producing a `.dll` locally with the [Type Library Importer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer) utility.

Comment: Your solution worked Jimi. If you post it as an answer I will accept it